# Query to get all table names

Tags: asp.net, sql

Can any one tell me that how to get names of all tables of a database using asp.net

Answer (score 4):

A newer method on SQL Server is to use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) to get the information:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
```

This particular view also includes Views in its list of tables, which is why you need the where clause.

Comment: +1. This is a better and more portable method than mine, although it's a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which database engine you are using. On SQL Server, you can query the `sysobjects` table and filter for objects with type `U`:

```
SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are interested in the MySQL way to achieve this, you can use

```
DESCRIBE tableName;
```